# How to include automatically all classes, methods and functions in a sphinx documentation?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I try to create a html documentation for a project containing several thousand classes using sphinx and it's autodoc plugin. *sphinx-apidoc* creates wonderful rst-files, but lacks of an automatic creation of *autoclasses* and *automethods*.

**Is there a way/command/utility in sphinx to auto-include all variables, functions, classes and decorators in the documentation?**

Some sample code of one rst-file:

```
tagger Package
=================

:mod:`tagger` Package
------------------------
.. automodule:: project.tagger
    :members:


:mod:`client` Module
--------------------
.. automodule:: project.analyzers.tagger.client
    :members:
```

Comment: Have you already checked the [`autodoc` extension](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html#module-sphinx.ext.autodoc)?

Comment: the autodoc extension is added in the conf.py:
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'sphinx.ext.viewcode']

Sphinx detects all modules but it doesn't list the classes and it methods.

Comment: According to above autodoc extension 'Members without docstrings will be left out, unless you give the undoc-members flag option'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a Sphinx extension which will help you in this called [autodoc](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html).

If you want to include the class then you have to write:

```
.. autoclass:: <ClassName>
```

Similarly for a method:

```
.. automethod:: <MethodName>
```

Comment: I use autodoc. This means that I would have to add ..autoclass more than thousand times or create a script. Isn't there an autodetection?

Comment: You can use `automodule` If you want to automatically document members, there’s a members option. Please check the link. There are many option in the autodoc extension.

Comment: for me adding :members: and :undoc-members: did the trick